# Topology induced by the pseudo-hyperbolic metric

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathbb{D}$ be the unit disc in the complex plane and let $d\colon \mathbb{D}\times\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{R}$ be the pseudo-hyperbolic metric, i.e.,
$$d(z,w) = \left|\frac{z-w}{1-\bar zw}\right|,\quad z,w\in\mathbb{D}.$$

One can verify that any ball w.r.t. the metric $d$ is also a standard ball. More precisely, let $\Delta(p,r) = \{z\in\mathbb{D}\mid d(p,z)<r\}$, then
$$\Delta(p,r) = B\biggl(\frac{1-r^2}{1- |p|^2r^2}p, \frac{1-|p|^2}{1-|p|^2r^2}r \biggr).$$

**My question:** the map
$$(p,r)\longmapsto \biggl(\frac{1-r^2}{1- |p|^2r^2}p, \frac{1-|p|^2}{1-|p|^2r^2}r \biggr)$$
is a surjection from $\mathbb{D}\times (0,1)\to \mathbb{D}\times (0,1)$ or not?

If it is, then we can say that and standard ball in $\mathbb{D}$ can also be represented as a $d$-ball and therefore the metric $d$ induces the same topology as the standard toplogy.